# What is the best practice to represent a CNN network by text?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution

What is the best practice to represent a CNN network by text?

for example the following text is a common way to representing a CNN network:

```
INPUT -> CONV -> RELU -> FC
```

But input size, filter (kernel) size, number of strides, padding and many parameters in each layer does not specified.

Is there any best practice to representing a CNN network (for example AlexNet) by text?

Answer (score 0):

Text like this is less common. In papers there are two common ways. First tables have been widely used to convey the structure of a NN, purely with text. An example for this would be the VGG networks(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf).

The other common way, which does not purely use text, is to show a graph as is done by the ResNet Paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf) or the inception networks.